# mobiscroll date/time .setdate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ios, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am pretty new to mobile stuff, jquery...  Here is the situation I 
have an asp.net page, and I am using jquery mobile.  Everything is 
going well.  I am trying to get mobiscroll date/time selector to work the way I want.  I 
have the mobiscroll selector able to populate the textbox field, and I 
then use this value to update the database.  All is well

When I try to update the data through the same form I run into 
problems.   I can query the database, and populate the form items with 
the appropiate date/time  stored in the database, but when I click 
into the date/time textbox, the mobiscroll selector shows todays date, 
and not the date that was poplulated into the textbox.

I have tried using setdate with no success, and a snippet of code that 
used the beforeShow event, again with no success.

I am confused, if the mobiscroll control can open by clicking into the 
textbox why wouldn't it set the date/time if it had a value in the 
textbox, or am I doing something wrong?

Can someone please clarify this for me, and show me a snippet of code 
that with set the date of the mobiscroll from the textbox it is tied 
too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this post http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/issues/detail?id=44

Try changing the format of the date you are setting.

> Comment 2 by project member diosla...@gmail.com, Oct 17, 2011
>
> Well... it does not appear in the documentation, but you must use 'yy'
>   for 4 digit, and 'y' for 2 digit year format in your dateFormat
>   option, like in the jquery UI datepicker. In your case change
>   'dd.mm.yyyy' to 'dd.mm.yy' and your problem is gone.